When is a ring complete with respect to its nilradical?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $I$ be its nilradical. When is $R$ complete with respect to $I$?
For example, if $I$ is finitely generated, there exists $N$ such that $I^N = 0$ and thus $R$ is complete with respect to $I$.

For the same reason it's true if the nilradical is itself a nilpotent ideal. I doubt it's necessary, but one necessary condition is $\bigcap_n I^n={0}$, so for instance taking something like the Puiseaux ring modulo $x$ will give a nonexample. I'm not sure exactly what kind of answer you expect.
